# Auto Copy & Paste specific columns depending on ComboBox value

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I've been putting together a macro that reads in cells from *`Sheet1`* and places them onto a ComboBox on a *`Sheet2`*

This macro copies the column of the selected cell to a column on *`Sheet2`*.

So far I have been able to do this but it requires referencing each cell  and running the macro each time.

I'm looking for an automatic update of the column once the ComboBox value changes and to use only one 'If statement' to Copy and Paste the column.

Here's my code so far:

```
Option Explicit

 Sub ComboBox1_Change()

 Dim cmbx As ComboBox
 Dim myRange As Range
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim c As Range

 Set cmbx = Sheet2.ComboBox1
 cmbx.Clear

 Set myRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:I4")
 For Each c In myRange

   If c.Value <> "" Then
     cmbx.AddItem c.Value
     cmbx.ListIndex = 0
   End If

 Next

   If (cmbx.ListIndex = 0) Then
     With ActiveSheet
      .Range(.Range("D4"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count)).Copy
     End With
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4")
   End If

   If (cmbx.ListIndex = 1) Then
     With ActiveSheet
      .Range(.Range("E4"), .Range("E" & .Rows.Count)).Copy
     End With
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4")
   End If

   If (cmbx.ListIndex = 2) Then
     With ActiveSheet
      .Range(.Range("F4"), .Range("F" & .Rows.Count)).Copy
     End With
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4")
   End If

   If (cmbx.ListIndex = 3) Then
     With ActiveSheet
      .Range(.Range("G4"), .Range("G" & .Rows.Count)).Copy
     End With
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4")
   End If

   If (cmbx.ListIndex = 4) Then
     With ActiveSheet
      .Range(.Range("H4"), .Range("H" & .Rows.Count)).Copy
     End With
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4")
   End If

   If (cmbx.ListIndex = 5) Then
     With ActiveSheet
      .Range(.Range("I4"), .Range("I" & .Rows.Count)).Copy
     End With
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4")
   End If

End Sub
```

### EDIT:

Just realised this code only works when ListIndex is 0 and that *ListIndex* is not the right function to use. This had worked for the first item in the ComboBox. Not yet sure what needs to be changed.

---

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So now tell me the issue

Comment: I have *`Sheet1`* with product data of **X** products on **X** columns respectively. On *`Sheet2`* I have a ComboBox where the labels for each product is loaded. Whatever is selected on the ComboBox has it's column automatically copied over to a column on *`Sheet2`*. Let me know if that's not clear enough, I've been having trouble explaning this in a concise manner.

Comment: @RobertEnglish how did you create your ComboBox objects

Comment: In the first For statement

Comment: I've rolled this back to before mehow's answer. Please do not do any further edits which change the issues in your code.

Comment: Did u solve the issue??

Comment: Unfortunately, no. All suggestions/help/answers are welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Add the data as shown below to Sheet1:**

[image]

**Open the VBA Editor/IDE.  Create userform1 and drag/drop a combobox1.**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C1")
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem (cell.Value)
    Next cell
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Select Case True
    Case ComboBox1.Text = "fruit"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A100").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
    Case ComboBox1.Text = "vegetable"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B100").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
    Case ComboBox1.Text = "tree"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C100").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
End Select

End Sub
```

**Under Worksheet2 in the VBA Editor, add**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Example file found [here](http://www.stndip.com/downloads/book1.xls).